# How to scrape Next button on Linkedin with Selenium using Python?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, scroll, webdriverwait

I am trying to scrape LinkedIn website using Selenium. I can't parse Next button. It resists as much as it can. I've spent a half of a day to adress this, but all in vain.

I tried absolutely various options, with text and so on. Only work with start ID but scrape other button.

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[@aria-label='Далее']"}
```

This is quite common for this site:

```
//*[starts-with(@id,'e')]
```

My code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from time import sleep



chrome_driver_path = Service("E:\programming\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=chrome_driver_path)
url = "https://www.linkedin.com/feed/"
driver.get(url)
SEARCH_QUERY = "python developer"
LOGIN = "EMAIL"
PASSWORD = "PASSWORD"
sleep(10)

sign_in_link = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/main/p[1]/a')
sign_in_link.click()

login_input = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="username"]')
login_input.send_keys(LOGIN)
sleep(1)
password_input = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="password"]')
password_input.send_keys(PASSWORD)
sleep(1)
enter_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="organic-div"]/form/div[3]/button')
enter_button.click()
sleep(25)

lens_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="global-nav-search"]/div/button')
lens_button.click()
sleep(5)

search_input = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="global-nav-typeahead"]/input')
search_input.send_keys(SEARCH_QUERY)
search_input.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
sleep(5)

people_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="search-reusables__filters-bar"]/ul/li[1]/button')
people_button.click()
sleep(5)

page_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@aria-label='Далее']")
page_button.click()

sleep(60)
```

[Chrome inspection of button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjnBr.png)
[Next Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gz6IU.png)

Comment: Please share ALL your selenium code

Comment: Added my code .

Comment: I asked for **ALL** relevant code.

Comment: shared all relevant code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, there are several issues here:

1. The main problem why your code not worked is because the "next" pagination is initially even not created on the page until you scrolling the page, so I added the mechanism, to scroll the page until that button can be clicked.
2. it's not good to create locators based on local language texts.
3. You should use `WebDriverWait` `expected_conditions` explicit waits, not hardcoded pauses.

I used mixed locators types to show that sometimes it's better to use `By.ID` and sometimes `By.XPATH` etc.
the following code works:

```py
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=webdriver_service)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

url = "https://www.linkedin.com/feed/"
driver.get(url)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@href,'login')]"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "username"))).send_keys(my_email)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "password"))).send_keys(my_password)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[type='submit']"))).click()
search_input = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[contains(@class,'search-global')]")))
search_input.click()
search_input.send_keys("python developer" + Keys.ENTER)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="search-reusables__filters-bar"]/ul/li[1]/button'))).click()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 4)
while True:
    try:
        next_btn = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.artdeco-pagination__button.artdeco-pagination__button--next")))
        next_btn.location_once_scrolled_into_view
        time.sleep(0.2)
        next_btn.click()
        break
    except:
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, arguments[0]);", 600)
```

Comment: You've hit the nail on the head! I didn't even think about scrolling. And thanks for the recommendations! I'll take your answer as a sample of good code.

Comment: You are welcome! I'm always happy to share my professional knowledge and what you see here are a very basic things.

Comment: That's amazing. I also didn't even think about scrolling. So the code was unable to detect the pagination button. Thank you!

Comment: I'm happy it was useful 